# Related to network (Firebase Realtime database connectivity)

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, electron

I have developed a desktop application as a server using electron and node.js.

Database: Firebase Realtime database.
node.js for: rest API.

this desktop application work on the local network(office network).
this server starts every morning and closes every night.

this server working fine. but one day when I start the server, the server is not getting data and not giving any error.

I have added an admin service account so the rule for a real-time database is ok.
internet is working really good(high speed)

after encountering this problem I check this server on another computer but still the same problem.

then I connect mobile network hotspot to computer then I start the server again then server getting data from firebase real-time database so server start working

so I try again using the office network but the same problem. (server working fine using mobile hotspot but not working with office network but why?)

Firebase code for getting data. (I am not getting any type of error here)

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db
    .ref()
    .child('data');
ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() != undefined) {
    }
    res.send('ok');
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

I also try restating the router of the network but the same problem

so I don't understand why it is happening and how to solve it.

can anyone give the right direction?

if more information needed please ask in a comment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

It sounds like the traffic is not reaching the Firebase database servers over that network. We've seen this happen recently when some ISPs in south-east Asia started blocking access to certain Firebase services.

Our regional team has reached out to those ISPs to work with them on allowing this traffic. I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) so that your ISP is also known, **and** reaching out to your provider directly to ask them to stop blocking this traffic.

Comment: can you tell why they block?

Comment: You will have to reach out to the ISP to hear why they are blocking traffic.

Comment: sir, I have gone to firebase support but I am confused and don't know what to do? so please can u give a more detailed explanation of how to reach out to Firebase support for my particular problem.